# XML string to dataframe keeps transforming with unwanted characters

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, elementtree

i am trying to create a XML in a column from a dataframe.
But as a standard XML. i keep getting not the right output, for now i keep getting "b'" before the XML and the XML ends with an '

**See below for an example**

```
b'<Item><ItemInformation><DescriptionModule><Information><Name>DropShots</Name></Information></DescriptionModule></ItemInformation></Item>'
```

**My code: **

```py
XMLstring = ET.tostring((E.Item(E.ItemInformation(E.DescriptionModule(E.Information(E.Name(Value)))))))

df = spark.createDataFrame([("123", str(XMLstring))],["Rule_Id", "XML"])
display(df)
```

**and i expected:**

```
Rule_Id XML
123 
        <Item><ItemInformation><DescriptionModule><Information><Name>DropShots</Name></Information></DescriptionModule></ItemInformation></Item>
```

**but i got:**

```
Rule_Id XML
123 
        b'<Item><ItemInformation><DescriptionModule><Information><Name>DropShots</Name></Information></DescriptionModule></ItemInformation></Item>'`
```

Comment: `tostring()` returns a `bytes` object (unless `encoding="unicode"` is used). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269765/407651.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [`.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to the end of your `.tostring()`...

```py
XMLstring = ET.tostring((E.Item(E.ItemInformation(E.DescriptionModule(E.Information(E.Name(Value))))))).decode()
```